# how to get a particular row from a data frame with if else

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame (df) with ncol=1; nrow=2128.

this is the data structure:

```
208    INCL10
209    0.006882
210    INCL11
211    0.006780
212    INCL12
213    0.006590
214    INCL13
215    0.005693
216    INCL14
217    0.005225
```

So i want to know what is the value for INCL10 automatically (that is 0.006882).
i have this script:

```
for(i in 1:length(df[,1])) {if (df[i,1]=="INCL10") {INCL10=df[i+1,1]}  else CALENDARDATE="none" }
```

but when i evaluate the sentence the result is `"none"`

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use which to get the index of "INCL10" then add 1 to get the next row.

```
data <- data.frame(X = c("INCL10", ".006882", "INCL11", ".00678", "INCL12", "0.006590", "INCL13", "0.005693", "INCL14", "0.005225"))


data[which(data$X == "INCL10") + 1, ]
```

Comment: what should i use if in one table i dont have the row "INCL10"? i was using `else INCL10="none"`, but i thing that with this method i cant

Comment: Using this it will return  "character(0)". What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @Pau, you can modify this solution to `ifelse(any(data$X == "INCL10"), as.character(data[which(data$X == "INCL10") + 1, ]), "non")`